# Program to convert hexadecimal to decimal not working

Tags: c++, c++11, hex, decimal

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x,i,y,d=0;
    char c[255];
    gets(c);
    for(i=0;c[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(c[i]>=0 && c[i]<=9)
        {
            x=c[i];
            cout<<x;
            d=(d*16)+x;
        }
        else if(c[i]>=65 && c[i]<=90)
        {
            y=c[i]-55;
            d=(d*16)+y;
        }
    }
    cout<<d;
    return 0;
}
```

Here integer d will be the decimal number. The program upon running in Code::Blocks doesn't show any errors.
Thank you for help :)

Comment: whats specifically not working?

Comment: `gets(c)` why would you do this. Several better ways to read in information. Also what isnt working

Comment: Or simply use [stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) for the task.

Comment: x=c[i];
cout<<x;
d=(d*16)+x;  think about how do they work harder and you should be able to get it by yourself

Answer (score 2):

Your keyboard input will return ASCII-characters, i.e. `'0'`..`'9'`, which is `30..39`, not `0..9`. Similarly, `'A'` is `65` (not `55`):

```
    if(c[i]>='0' && c[i]<='9')
    {
        x=c[i] - '0';
        cout<<x;
        d=(d*16)+x;
    }
    else if(c[i]>='A' && c[i]<='F')
    {
        y=c[i] - 'A';
        d=(d*16)+y;
    }
```

Comment: Suggest use of `if ( c[i] >= 'A' && c[i] <= 'F' )` and `y = c[i] - 'A';`.